# MySQL MATCH with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, alias, match, keyword

I'm building a feature that looks-up similar items to what user is inputting in the form. 
The user fills in two fields: type and manufacturer

I want to search for records in my database that match their corresponding values and return the best matches first.

I have a query that assigns a score to each field:

```
SELECT id, manuf, model, type, MATCH(manuf) AGAINST('BMW') AS `score_manuf`, MATCH(type) AGAINST('Car') AS `score_type` FROM `items`
```

This actually works and produces the scores.

Now I want to calculate the total score, that is the sum of two scores, to be later used to sort the results:

```
SELECT id, manuf, model, type, MATCH(manuf) AGAINST('BMW') AS `score_manuf`, MATCH(type) AGAINST('Car') AS `score_type`, (score_manuf + score_type) as 'score' FROM `items`
```

When I run this query, I get an error saying that "score_manuf" is an unknown column.

Can I not run arithmetic on alias fields? Or perhaps there is another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, manuf, model, type,
       @m := MATCH(manuf) AGAINST('BMW') AS score_manuf,
       @t := MATCH(type) AGAINST('Car') AS score_type,
       @m + @t as score
  FROM items;
```

This is the way you define [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)